# Load a Lockbox 2 public key into Lockbox 3

Tags: lockbox-3

I'm trying to convert some code from LB2 to LB3 and have hit a bit of a wall.

I have a very basic 256-bit RSA public key which I use with LB2 but can't seem to load into LB3.

The key is basically just a block of 41 bytes which I can load by simply calling TLbRSASSA.PublicKey.LoadFromStream.  I'm using the key for some simply signing.

I just can't get this key to load into LB3 at all no matter what I do.  If I use LB3 to generate a similar 256-bit key and save it to a file, the format is different, with what looks like a header containing "LockBox3" and so forth.

Can anyone offer a simple explanation of how to load this 41-byte public key into LB3 so I can continue to verify signatures with it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

LB2 keys are not compatible with LB3 keys.

If you want to upgrade to LB3, you will need to generate new keys.

Comment: Seriously?! That's going to be a major in the neck for us. I'll continue to use LB2 for now, the only major issue is that it's not 64-bit compatible.  When the time comes to revisit 64-bit I'll re-evaluate but frankly I think I might look at alternative solutions next time.

Comment: LB2 is currently being upgraded for new compilers (XE6 etc), so you should be able to do 64 bit with it. I believe the XE6 support is in the SVN repository, but not yet in the officially released installer binary.